# Where to ask: drilling holes in threaded rod

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Where should I ask a question about drilling holes in threaded rod for cotter pins? My first guess was DIY, but this is for a hobby project (cubmobile) and it is explicitly diasallowed in the FAQ. I also looked at a few others, but none had existing questions that seemed related.

Comment: While it might be considered off-topic on DIY.SE, you could try asking your question in [their chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111/home-improvement) to see if there is someone willing to provide assistance on your project.

Comment: +1 I'm not native speaker, I have never heard of something like that, I've typed it in google and I haven't found a link to SE except that question here. It should be in SE anywhere :)

Comment: It might also fly over on [Mechanics.SE], even though there's no _motor_ involved.